# Return all the employees from array of objects

Tags: java

I have a getArray method which maps an employee to concrete classes but only return the first condition which HR and leaves the rest of objects. here is the methods and it'll be helpful if it colud return all the objects

```
public static Employee getArray() {
    List < Employee > employees = DataAccess.readFile("employees.txt");
    Employee emp = null;
    //System.out.println(employees);
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {

        if (employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment().equals("HR")) {
            emp = new SupportStaff(employees.get(i).getEmployeeId(), employees.get(i).getFirst_name(), employees.get(i).getLast_name(),
                employees.get(i).getDOB(), employees.get(i).getGender(), employees.get(i).getAddress(),
                employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment(), employees.get(i).getDateHired(), employees.get(i).getHoursWorked(),
                employees.get(i).getRateOfPay(), employees.get(i).getCarAllowance(), employees.get(i).getMonthlyPay(),
                employees.get(i).getTaxRate());
        } else if (employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment().equals("Sales")) {
            emp = new SupportStaff(employees.get(i).getEmployeeId(), employees.get(i).getFirst_name(), employees.get(i).getLast_name(),
                employees.get(i).getDOB(), employees.get(i).getGender(), employees.get(i).getAddress(),
                employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment(), employees.get(i).getDateHired(), employees.get(i).getHoursWorked(),
                employees.get(i).getRateOfPay(), employees.get(i).getCarAllowance(), employees.get(i).getMonthlyPay(),
                employees.get(i).getTaxRate());
        } else if (employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment().equals("Drivers")) {
            emp = new SupportStaff(employees.get(i).getEmployeeId(), employees.get(i).getFirst_name(), employees.get(i).getLast_name(),
                employees.get(i).getDOB(), employees.get(i).getGender(), employees.get(i).getAddress(),
                employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment(), employees.get(i).getDateHired(), employees.get(i).getHoursWorked(),
                employees.get(i).getRateOfPay(), employees.get(i).getCarAllowance(), employees.get(i).getMonthlyPay(),
                employees.get(i).getTaxRate());
        } else if (employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment().equals("Tour Operator")) {
            emp = new SupportStaff(employees.get(i).getEmployeeId(), employees.get(i).getFirst_name(), employees.get(i).getLast_name(),
                employees.get(i).getDOB(), employees.get(i).getGender(), employees.get(i).getAddress(),
                employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment(), employees.get(i).getDateHired(), employees.get(i).getHoursWorked(),
                employees.get(i).getRateOfPay(), employees.get(i).getCarAllowance(), employees.get(i).getMonthlyPay(),
                employees.get(i).getTaxRate());
        } else if (employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment().equals("Accounting Officer")) {
            emp = new SupportStaff(employees.get(i).getEmployeeId(), employees.get(i).getFirst_name(), employees.get(i).getLast_name(),
                employees.get(i).getDOB(), employees.get(i).getGender(), employees.get(i).getAddress(),
                employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment(), employees.get(i).getDateHired(), employees.get(i).getHoursWorked(),
                employees.get(i).getRateOfPay(), employees.get(i).getCarAllowance(), employees.get(i).getMonthlyPay(),
                employees.get(i).getTaxRate());

        } else if (employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment().contains("Management")) {
            emp = new Management(employees.get(i).getEmployeeId(), employees.get(i).getFirst_name(), employees.get(i).getLast_name(),
                employees.get(i).getDOB(), employees.get(i).getGender(), employees.get(i).getAddress(),
                employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment(), employees.get(i).getDateHired(), employees.get(i).getHoursWorked(),
                employees.get(i).getRateOfPay(), employees.get(i).getCarAllowance(), employees.get(i).getMonthlyPay(),
                employees.get(i).getTaxRate());
        } else {
            System.out.println("not recognised");
        }

    }
    return emp;
}
```

Comment: 1. The `getArray()` method only returns a single Employee - not an array/List of employees. 2. You already have a List of Employee in `employees`. 3. The DRY principle comes to mind over and over and over again.

Comment: what should I do, i go get the whole list of employees

Comment: Do `SupportStaff` and `Management` extend the `Employee` class?

Comment: yes and i read the employees from a textfile

Comment: This: "_what should I do_" - given the limited information you've provided, it does not appear that there is anything that differentiates any of these employee types. So _what you should do_ is leave them all as Employee types. If the only thing that differentiates these types is the name of the class, that is no justification. Name the variable "management" or "staffEmployee" - and realize they are exactly the same type: Employee.

Comment: I have super class employee which is extended by SupportStaff and Management. I read from a textfile to an array of objects and i wanted to map each employee to each class by title of employment

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't taken that the wrong way now:

The following else-if conditions are only triggered if the expression `(employees.get(i).getTitleOfEmployment().equals("HR"))` is `false`.

As soon as the first if-condition is fulfilled / `true`, the following else-if conditions are no longer taken into account.

If you only get back employees with "HR", it is probably because in `employees.txt` all employees have the value "HR" as `titleOfEmployment`.

Comment: so then,switch statement would be ideal for this?

Comment: That wouldn´t make any difference, because if Java reaches a break keyword, it breaks out of the switch block. It would basically do the same as your if/else-if tree.

Comment: can you please suggest the alternative,I am stuck

Comment: I have a super class employee and cocrete classes that i want to map employees to

Answer (score 0):

If `SupportStaff` and `Management` extend the `Employee` class, you could change your code as follows.
Add a constructor to your classes `SupportStaff` and `Management` that accepts an `Employee` object.

For Example:

```
Management(Employee employee) {
    this(employee.getEmployeeId(), employee.getFirst_name(), employee.getLast_name(),
         employee.getDOB(), employee.getGender(), employee.getAddress(),
         employee.getTitleOfEmployment(), employee.getDateHired(), employee.getHoursWorked(),
         employee.getRateOfPay(), employee.getCarAllowance(), employee.getMonthlyPay(),
         employee.getTaxRate());
}
```

Then change your code something like this:

```
public static List<Employee> getArray() {
    List<Employee> employees = DataAccess.readFile("employees.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < employees.size(); i++) {
        Employee employee = employees.get(i);
        if (employee.getTitleOfEmployment().contains("Management")) {
            employees.set(i, new Management(employee));
        } else {
            employees.set(i, new SupportStaff(employee));
        }
    } 
    return employees;
}
```

`getArray()` now returns a List with the adapted types.

Comment: ok thanks, but i have already have super() in the extended classes,why do i need the other constructor again.I am new to java please

Comment: When you create a `Management` Object, you can also use it as an `Employee` Object, but an `Employee` Object is not automatically a `Management` Object too! The additional constructor also avoids redundancies.

Comment: the **public static List<Employee> getArray()** gives me an error when i call it in another class like this ** String ln = DataAccess.getArray().getLast_name();**

Comment: It's no wonder, because `getArray()` now returns a `List<Employee>`. You have to select an `Employee` from the list. As an example `for (Employee employee : DataAccess.getArray ()) System.out.println(employee.getLast_name())` would output all names on the console.